# What is the difference between Apache Tomcat and Jenkins?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

Jenkins is an open source continuous integration tool written in Java.
It is a server-based system running in a servlet container such as Apache Tomcat.
I have confused how it work on Tomcat, and may i know the Difference between these two?

Comment: You've explained it yourself. Tomcat is a JEE servlet container engine and Jenkins is an Java web application that can be deployed onto tomcat. The confusing part may be that Jenkins also packages its own webserver jars, enabling easy deployment.

Comment: ?? You're giving the answer yourself in the first two sentences. Tomcat is not a CI tool, Jenkins is. Tomcat is a servlet container, Jenkins isn't. What's in there that you get confused about?

Comment: I think the question was more about the technical structure of Jenkins vs Tomcat.  I'm not entirely sure how Jenkins uses JRE to present a listening service, and how it handles multiple connections, but as I understand it, it's a single webapp, whereas Tomcat is designed to host multiple webapp's and serve them on multiple listening sockets.  Personally I'd like to know the crossover for the purposes of identifying security flaws in Jenkins where Tomcat has them.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in your question, [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) is a platform to allow continuous integration - in simple words automation of procedures involved in development process. One of its common uses is to allow quick deployments of your code to your server whether if it's development or production.

Jenkins also has lots of plugins that allows you to do variety of tasks.
For example, let's say you have a team of developers that work on a project.
Now, you don't want them to waste time on manual build and deploy their code to the test server. Jenkins is very handy in those cases, since using a simple UI, you can setup a build and deploy process that includes repository checkout (svn, git and more), build process (ANT for example if used), SCP / SSH transfer and remote command and deploy it on your server (Tomcat for example).

Meaning, your developers, just need to login and press the build button... everything will happen behind the scene - mostly, it keeps the standards of the work process.

This is one simple example, but keep in mind that it's very versatile and you can do a lot with it.

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) on the other hand is a JAVA servlet container, that run your JAVA webapp (a quite good one if I may add).

Let me know if you not more details or examples.

Hope it helped,

Liron